# AngularJS directive linking

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I've been reading a lot about AngularJS directives, and how their lifecycle consists of executing the compile, controller, pre-link, and post-link functions. However, I'm curious about 2 things:

1. What are the inputs and outputs of these lifecycle functions? I.e. what does the compile function take as an input and what does it produce as the result for the controller function to execute?
2. I notice a lot of literature saying that as each child directive function is "linked", AngularJS will then execute the post-link function. What exactly does linking mean? What is the directive getting linked to?

Comment: Rather than take the time to answer this, I'll send you to the source that helped me understand the directive lifecycle. "**[The nitty-gritty of compile and link functions inside AngularJS](http://www.jvandemo.com/the-nitty-gritty-of-compile-and-link-functions-inside-angularjs-directives/)**" by Jurgen Van de Moere.

Comment: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile